# Changing default lifetime manager of Unity container

Tags: unity-container, prism

Is there any way to make the ContainerControlledLifetimeManager the default lifetime manager for Unity container which is used with implicit registration e.g. through "registration by convention"? I basically want to have everything registered as Singleton unless explicitly registered differently.

Note: I use Unity in combination with Prism library so in case there is a solution with Prism that would be sufficient as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify `WithLifetime.ContainerControlled` when using registration-by-convention, like

```
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterTypes( AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath(),
                                                WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
                                                WithName.Default,
                                                WithLifetime.ContainerControlled );
```

You could also put your singletons into a folder `Services` and only register those with `ContainerControlled`.

Comment: Works ;-) is there also a way to achieve the same without "registration by convention"? In prism I don't have to register anything but still everything is composed correctly. Any container configuration which can be applied in the bootstraper?

Comment: Do you use interfaces? That you can have types resolved directly without registration is more of a side-effect in my oppinion, and with interfaces you have to register your types. So I'm unsure what you mean by "in prism I don't have to register anything", but if you mean that you want `Resolve<MyService>()` to create a singleton without `Register<MyService>( new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() )`, then no, I think there's nothing right out of the box. But you can create an extension for unity, I'm pretty sure, one can hook somewhere to change that behaviour...

Comment: Yes I have some classes I use without interfaces for now and here the side effect was quite handy. Anyhow I will continue with your suggestions for now. Thx